# How to use Jetpack Compose ConstraintLayout together with Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to test a simple layout in compose:

A ConstraintLayout (yellow) wrapping

- StickyTopText (green)
- a Scrolling View (gray)
- StickyBottomText (yellow)

I implemented it like this:

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun MapOverlay() {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {

        val (stickyTop, scroller, stickyBottom) = createRefs()

        Text(text = "Sticky Top Text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(stickyTop) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                }
                .background(Color.Green)
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(scroller) {
                    top.linkTo(stickyTop.bottom)
                    bottom.linkTo(stickyBottom.top)
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            repeat(80) {
                Text(
                    text = "This is Test $it of 80",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.LightGray)
                )
            }
        }

        Text(text = "Sticky Bottom Text",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .constrainAs(stickyBottom) {
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    })
        }
    }
```

Most of it works pretty fine, except the list getting cut off at the end at item 77 instead of 80: (79; zero-Indexed)

[image: Cut off List]

What am i doing wrong? Or is this a bug?
(I know i might do this via a scaffold, but that seemed over engineered. Also i would like to *understand* the issue, not circumvent it

Compose version 1.0.0-beta09

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. The statement `height = Dimension.fillToConstraints`, and set the ConstraintLayout's height as `fillMaxHeight()` helped me. Voted up! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your code and it's really not working on `1.0.0-alpha07`, but it's working on `1.0.0-alpha08` (and compose `1.0.0-beta09`)

Also, is there any particular reason you're using `ConstraintLayout`? You can achieve the same result using this code:

```kotlin
Column(
    Modifier
        .background(Color.Yellow)
        .fillMaxHeight()
) {
    Text("Sticky Top Text", Modifier.background(Color.Green))
    Column(
        Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        repeat(80) {
            Text(
                "This is Test ${it + 1} of 80",
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
            )
        }
    }
    Text("Sticky Bottom Text", Modifier.background(Color.Red))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding that versioning-bug: our "main" compose was beta09, but someone had hardcoded the alpha-07 for the constraint-layout dependency. Increasing it to alpha-08 solved the bug.

Comment: About the layout: It's the basic layout with which i could reproduce the behavior, the screen is quite a bit more complicated

Comment: This is not working for me on 1.0.5

Comment: I just tested on 1.1.0-beta04 and it's working.

Comment: I tried this with a scrollable column over a spacer over a button over a spacer.  And the layout just shoved the column under spacer/button elements!  A) It's annoying and B) I didn't think this was suppose to happen unless you had a box.